# updating ui of activity from service using handler not call oncreate() and start()Command of service

Tags: android, service, handler

i m using handler to update ui or show toast every 15 seconds of activity class from service so i have defined handler object in activity and use handler method MainActivity.handler.sendemptymessage() from service class to update ui or show toast every 15 seconds but what happen when i start service click of button oncreate() of service class not showing me toast like sevice is created also onStartCommand toast is not showing and only once toast of activity class is shows not showing repeatedly so, what is wrong in my following code it's proper way that i defined handler object in activity class or not i cant figure out that please give me proper solution. i know other component to update ui from service to activity but i only want to achieve this by handler and sendemptymessage.thanks in advance

**MainActivity-->**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    static Activity thisActivity = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        thisActivity = this;


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceDemo.class));
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceDemo.class));
            }

        });

    }

    static Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // This is where main activity thread receives messages
            // Put here your handling of incoming messages posted by other
            // threads
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            if (msg.what == 0) {

                show();
            }
        }

    };

    public static void show() {

        Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "recive called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
```

}

**Service.class**-->

```
public class ServiceDemo extends Service {
    int mStartMode;
    /** interface for clients that bind */
    IBinder mBinder;
    /** indicates whether onRebind should be used */
    boolean mAllowRebind;

    /** Called when the service is being created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " service created",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service started",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
                MainActivity.handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mStartMode;
        }

    }

    /** A client is binding to the service with bindService() */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** Called when all clients have unbound with unbindService() */
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return mAllowRebind;
    }

    /** Called when a client is binding to the service with bindService() */
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {

    }

    /** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service destroyed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the Handler or whatever you take, when you need to update Ui than Use,

```
runOnUiThread(new  Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    //Code for ui update
                }
            });
```

Comment: currently u r facing any error? than plz directly show it

Comment: i want to update ui through only handler and handler.sendemptymessage() as my handler is static so its not allow non static runonuiThread() inside handler to update ui u got my point.

Comment: i have described issue everything into my question u can check my code whats wrong in my code or not that why my toast not showing repeatedly only shows once from activity

Comment: hello brother thanks for your reply i got my solution that i have put the code Thread.sleep inside onstartcommand() in service class. it;s not proper way so i have started thread inside onstartcommand() and than sendemptymessage(0) it's works perfects.